# find the value of the integration $\int_0^{\infty} e^{(-au+bu^4-cu^2)}(du^3-eu)du$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, improper-integrals

How do I find the value of the integration $\int_0^{\infty} e^{(-au+bu^4-cu^2)}(fu^3-eu)(-i)du$ where $a,b,c,e,f$ are positive constant and $i=\sqrt{(-1)}$.

I have tried taking $b$ common and make square form on the power of exponential but I couldn't succeed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you think that $b>0$ could make a problem ?

Comment: One mistake was there, now its fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Not only there is no closed form for the antiderivative but $b>0$ shows divergence.

Make $a=b=c=d=e=1$ and integrate from $0$ to $10$; the result is $3.70 \times 10^{4294}$.